# Sorting in Pig using order by

Tags: sorting, hadoop, apache-pig

Hi I am new to Hadoop as well as Pig. 
When i try to sort my data using ORDER BY in pig, the output is not exactly in ascending order.
Input: 1,4,12,36,88,93,7
Code:

```
A = LOAD 'INPUT' using PigStorage();
B = ORDER A BY $0;`enter code here`
DUMP B;
```

Output: 1,12,36,4,7,88,93
which not correct. Please help me to get it in a correct way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare column $0 as a number, or use a cast. For example:

```
A = LOAD 'INPUT' using PigStorage() AS (a0:int, [extra columns here]);
B = ORDER A BY a0;
DUMP B;
```

Otherwise, it is essentially processed as a string.

Comment: @Rohit : Could you please close the Question, once you got the answer. Thanks !